# Form resubmission when page is refreshed even with unset method

Tags: php, forms, post

When refreshing my webpage, the form (see under) is submitted again and again even if I use unset to reset the $_POST values. For instance, if I had 10£ with my form, refreshing will add 10$ again and again.

I tried to use header('index.php') too but it doesn't seem to work. Maybe I didn't use it at the right line.

```
<?php
$daysPast = 10;

$file = fopen('expense.txt', 'r+');
$expenses = fgets($file);

if (isset($_POST['expenses']))
{
    $expenses += (float)$_POST['expense'];
    unset($_POST);
}
fseek($file, 0);
fputs($file, $expenses);
fclose($file);

echo "I spent " . $expense ."£ that is to say " . round($expenses/$daysPast,2) . "£ per day.";
echo "<hr />"
?>

<form action="index.php" method="post" align="center">
    <input type="text" name="expenses">
    <input type="submit" value="Add ">
</form>
```

I heard about the Post Redirect Get pattern but I cannot see how to use it in this situation.

Comment: `unset()` has no effect on form submissions, as the browser handles that part. The PRG pattern means you would need to split your code up. Handle the form and its processing (which writes to the expense.txt file) first, then use `header()` to redirect the browser to another page (or reload the current page without the form submission) that reads from the expense.txt file and outputs the current value.

Comment: you have a typo: `$expenses += (float)$_POST['expense'];` `$_POST['expense']` (singular) does not exist in your form, it should be  `$expenses += (float)$_POST['expenses'];`

Comment: Thanks @lovelace but the typo was made when redacting the post on stackoverflow. Code is okay.

Comment: The post/redirect pattern specifies that you first specify a location response header (note that it's a key/value pair) and then ideally exit the script; e.g: `header('Location: index.php'); exit();`